# Change Observable List to Hashmap Singleton

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2

I have a singleton to cache objects, from here I create an observable from a List, this List is a response from the API which is filled with objects. (JSON)

```
 private static BehaviorSubject<List<Model>> observableModelsList;
    private static Observable<List<Model>> observable = myAPI.loadModelsRx();
    private static Subscription subscription;
    private PoiSingleton() {
    }

    public static PoiSingleton getInstance() {
        return ourInstance;
    }

    public static void resetObservable() {
        observablePoisList = BehaviorSubject.create();

        if (subscription != null && !subscription.isUnsubscribed()) {
            subscription.unsubscribe();
        }
        subscription = observable.subscribe(new Subscriber<List<Model>>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
                // do nothing
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                observablePoisList.onError(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(List<Model> models) {
                observablePoisList.onNext(models);
            }
        });
    }


    public static Observable<List<Poi>> getPoisObservable() {
        if (observablePoisList == null) {
            resetObservable();
        }
        return observablePoisList;
    }
```

What I want to achieve is create a HashMap from the List, the key should be the ID of the object and the value the object itself.

I am new to Android and Retrofit/RxJava so in what method/stage is it responsible to create the HashMap?

Comment: Try `Observable.map()` operator

Comment: use `.flatMapIterable(i->i).toMap(Poi::getKey, Poi::getValue)` before the subscribe call.

Comment: @TassosBassoukos on the observable or observableModelsList?